# Should "culture"  in "Somali culture" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Should I capitalize *culture* in the following sentence?

> I am proud to share Somali culture with the community.

I know that proper nouns should be capitalized, but *culture* seems to be a generic noun with a proper modifier. Hence, I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: No, you shouldn't capitalize culture

Comment: Nor should you capitalize on culture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, "*culture* [is] a generic noun with a proper modifier".  In such cases, as long as the generic noun is not *part* of the proper name (i.e. part of the name *Somali*), you should not capitalize it.

> I am proud to share Somali culture with the community.